# "switch" statement only allows the first 2 "case" blocks - regardless of order: Why?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a straightforward Javascript `switch` statement.  I am debugging it in Firefox (using Firebug).

A benefit of Firebug's Javascript debugger is that valid lines of Javascript are indicated by green line numbers.

I have run into a very strange issue.

My Javascript code is only valid for the first two `case` blocks in a `switch` statement.  I include screenshots to demonstrate that **the `case` blocks themselves are valid** because when I place any of the `case` blocks in either of the first two positions, they run successfully.

Here is order #1 of the `case` blocks:

[image: Order #1 of <code>case</code> blocks]

In particular, **notice that the green line numbers stop** at the start of the third block.  This isn't just a visual issue; when I step with the debugger and reach the third block, Javascript **dies**.  When the first two `case` blocks are reached, the code runs successfully.

Here is order #2 of the `case` blocks - identical except for the order of the blocks:

[image: Order #2 of <code>case</code> blocks]

**Note that the ONLY difference is the order of the `case` blocks.**  This time, the first two `case` blocks execute successfully (when reached) - **including the `case` block that failed in the first screenshot**.  But Javascript **dies** when the third `case` block is reached (even though it succeeded when it was in the position shown in the first screenshot).

Here is order #3 of the `case` blocks - but you get the point:

[image: Order #3 of <code>case</code> blocks]

**Ditto in this case.**  The third `case` block causes Javascript to die **just because it's not in one of the first two positions**.

As much as I wish to question my sanity, there must be an explanation.  Help!

Comment: The first step is to [replicate it with a minimal, self-contained test case](http://sscce.org). Not only are you likely to figure it out when you do that, but if you don't, you have something you can share that others can try to help you figure out.

Comment: Indeed that's true, and usually I do.  I was hoping for something obvious, so I posted first - occasionally 8 straight hours of programming leads one to wish to save time.  But if I find no answer, I will proceed.

Comment: as tj said you should have posted it as code block inspite of images.so that we could test it on our system

Comment: There must be some odd non-visible character buried in there. If you delete all of the text of the switch then (apologies) retype it from scratch, I suspect you'll solve the problem. Or if you have access to `vi` or `vim`, they're great at highlighting odd characters.

Comment: Indeed, even with out an SSCCE, copying-and-pasting the actual code has solved this problem for others in the past here on SO, as the offending character (if that's what's going on) is frequently preserved.

Comment: Well there you have it.  I retyped from scratch - character for character (and added curly braces around each `case` block, not including the `break`) - and it works.  I have in the past on multiple occasions dealt with hidden characters that messed things up - but of course, when you need to think of the answer, you don't.

Comment: (Even without the curly braces, it works.  It really was a hidden character.)

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: How very weird, normally those prevent the script from being parsed at all. Glad that sorted it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual reason this kind of thing happens is that an unprintable character has managed to slip into the source code. One of the dozen or so Unicode space-like characters, etc. Usually when this question is asked on SO, that's the answer that's ultimately found. (That said, usually the problem presents as the code not working *at all*, rather than what you're describing.)

If you delete all of the text of the switch then (apologies) retype it from scratch, I suspect you'll solve the problem. Or if you have access to `vi` or `vim`, they're great at highlighting unusual characters.

Comment: This is the answer.  One side comment worth nothing, in case you have a thought: I copied the text wholesale and pasted into UltraEdit's Hex view, and found no special hidden characters.  Note that my debugger is on a different machine than my editor, and I have a sync application (Cubby) automatically synchronize, so perhaps *it* added the hidden character.

Comment: Very, very odd stuff. :-) Glad you got it sorted, and hopefully this (including your note above) will sort it out for others!